# How do I get the old values of an entity?

Tags: entity-framework, entity, objectcontext

How do I get the old values of an entity?

follows the example..

```
public void Update(User user)
    ValidateEntity(user, OperationType.Update);

    oldUser = (how do I get the old values ​​(database) of the entity User?)

    Set.Attach(user);
    Context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(user, EntityState.Modified);
    Context.SaveChanges();

    OnUpdated(user, oldUser);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void Update(User user)
    ValidateEntity(user, OperationType.Update);

    var oldUser = Set.Single(u => u.Id == user.Id);
    Context.Detach(oldUser);

    Set.Attach(user);
    Context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(user, EntityState.Modified);
    Context.SaveChanges();

    OnUpdated(user, oldUser);
}
```

Or this:

```
public void Update(User user) 
{
    ValidateEntity(user, OperationType.Update);

    var oldUser = Set.Single(u => u.Id == user.Id);
    Set.ApplyCurrentValues(user);
    Context.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave);

    OnUpdated(user, Context.ObjectStateManager.GetOjectStateEntry(user).OriginalValues);

    Context.AcceptAllChanges(); 
}
```

Comment: thanks, this worked, but lets another doubt.

How I can  get a entity from this DbDataRecord?

Answer (score 0):

I found one way of convert DbDataRecord  to entity type using reflection...

where http://www.instanceofanobject.com/2011/01/ef4-dbdatarecord-convertto.html

```
    public static class AnonymousTypeConversion
    {
        /// 
        /// Converts a single DbDataRwcord object into something else.
        /// The destination type must have a default constructor.
        /// 
        /// 
        /// 
        /// 
        public static T ConvertTo(this DbDataRecord record)
        {
            T item = Activator.CreateInstance();
            for (int f = 0; f 
        /// Converts a list of DbDataRecord to a list of something else.
        /// 
        /// 
        /// 
        /// 
        public static List ConvertTo(this List list)
        {
            List result = (List)Activator.CreateInstance>();

            list.ForEach(rec =>
            {
                result.Add(rec.ConvertTo());
            });

            return result;
        }
    }
```